# Unit Test getting MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call

Tags: unit-test

I need to do an update and I get an error "MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call"

I need this line updated

```
  Key_Staff_People__c bm4 = new Key_Staff_People__c(Contact__c = c2.id,First_Name__c='FName2', Last_Name__c='LName2',role__c = 'Account Manager');
```

This line is getting the error -->`update bm4`;

What do I need to add?

Comment: I guess you want to insert this record

Comment: No, update it. But I am missing something in the syntax.

Comment: if update then where is Id of Key_Staff_People__c  record?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to update it, you need to pass the id of an existing Key Staff People record in it like Key_Staff_People__c bm4 = new Key_Staff_People__c(id= bm3.id)

Since there is no id of this record in its own, it is giving you that error

Comment: Excellent. This worked.

Comment: strange... how you figure it out that bm3 is the variable name ?

Comment: That was just an example I took as a reference cuz the code snippet used bm4 so i thought bm3 must be the prior one :)